# Spring.NET how to set value of dictionary entry using SpEL

Tags: c#, .net, spring.net, spring-el

I'm having an issue setting a dictionary entry value using Spring.NET Expression Language in XML configuration. I have a PreferencesManager class that has a `Dictionary<string, string>` property that I want to configure via XML. One of the entries in the Dictionary is a string representing the Current Domain's Base Directory. My PreferencesManager class exposes this public property:

(Note, I am using a private setter because Spring.NET supports private setter injection and I want to maintain private accessibility)

```
public static Dictionary<string, string> DefaultPreferences
{
    get { return p_DefaultPreferences; }

    private set
    {
        p_DefaultPreferences = value;
    }
}
```

My XML configuration for this class looks like this:

```
<object id="PreferencesManager" type="TestProj.PreferencesManager, TestProj">
    <property name="DefaultPreferences">
        <dictionary key-type="string" value-type="string">
            <entry key="DefaultWordListLocation" 
                   expression="AppDomain.CurrentDomain.BaseDirectory" />
        </dictionary>
    </property>
</object>
```

My problem is that when the container initializes this object it throws a ConfigurationErrorsException: `Error creating context 'spring.root': Cannot initialize property or field node 'AppDomain' because the specified context is null.`

I have read the documentation on Spring.NET Expression Language at http://www.springframework.net/doc-latest/reference/html/expressions.html (which is woefully lacking in SpEL examples in XML configuration) but I guess I must be missing something. MSDN tells me that the AppDomain class is in the mscorlib.dll assembly so I shouldn't have to register the type with the Spring.NET TypeRegistry.

I don't believe it's because the Dictionary is static because I'm not having issues configuring other entries with string literals.

Is there something I'm overlooking here? Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1):

Try to change your SpEL expression like:

```
<object id="PreferencesManager" type="TestProj.PreferencesManager, TestProj">
  <property name="DefaultPreferences">
    <dictionary key-type="string" value-type="string">
        <entry key="DefaultWordListLocation" 
               expression="T(System.AppDomain).CurrentDomain.BaseDirectory" />
    </dictionary>
  </property>
</object>
```